# Getting duplicate result in SQL query

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm having trouble with this one. I've four tables as shown in the attached image. I query returns some values from 4th table and one value from 2nd table. It's giving the result but is duplicating. Could someone help me out here! Please see the image first.

```
SELECT PLD.buyersItemNo, PLD.description, PLD.totalPcsCtn AS Quantity, BOD.itemPrice
FROM tblPurchase_BuyerOrder BO, tblPurchase_BuyerOrder_Details BOD, tblPurchase_PackingList PL, tblPurchase_PackingList_Details PLD 
WHERE BOD.buyerOrderNoSId = BO.sId AND
      PL.buyerOrderNoSId = BO.sId AND
      PLD.packingListSId = PL.sId AND PL.invoiceNo='5569';
```

[image: Tables & sql query image]

Comment: Please use modern join syntax. The syntax your are using (separating tables with commas) is from the 80s.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Could you please give example?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Something like:

```
SELECT PLD.buyersItemNo, PLD.description, PLD.totalPcsCtn AS Quantity, BOD.itemPrice
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.PK = table2.FK
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.PK = tableX.FK
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table4.PK = tableY.FK
WHERE PL.invoiceNo='5569';
```

Comment: But this query is also giving same result (4 records instead of 2). I used SELECT PLD.buyersItemNo, PLD.description, PLD.totalPcsCtn AS Quantity, BOD.itemPrice
FROM tblPurchase_PackingList_Details PLD
LEFT JOIN tblPurchase_PackingList PL ON PLD.packingListSId = PL.sId
LEFT JOIN tblPurchase_BuyerOrder BO ON BO.sId = PL.buyerOrderNoSId
LEFT JOIN tblPurchase_BuyerOrder_Details BOD ON BOD.buyerOrderNoSId = BO.sId
WHERE PL.invoiceNo='5569';

Comment: in select ```sum(PLD.totalPcsCtn)``` and add ```GROUP BY PLD.buyersItemNo```